# iOS tableviewcell width not same as tableview

Tags: ios, ipad, uitableview, width

I am creating a custom tableviewcell, so i believe by default tableviewcell width will be as wide as tableview itself right?

So after tableview is created, I did:

```
NSLog(@"%f",self.view.frame.size.width);
```

... which returns 476.00, and when I am instantiating my custom tableviewcell it is returning 320 instead...

```
NSLog(@"%f", self.frame.size.width);
```

I want the value of 476 when or after creating the cell... Because I am using it as a guideline to see how many columns I should have...

So, how can I obtain the full cell width?? (btw, the cell does take the entire row, after I print the background as yellow)

Comment: Is this for iPhone or iPad?  Also, what kind of controller are you using and how did you set its frame (or did you set it)?

Comment: I just use a class extends from UIViewController, in this controller I keep an instance variable of tableView. i did not explicitly set a width on the custom cell, but i did set the width of the tableview by saying it should be as big as the parent container. please also see the answer i left below to the other replier.

Comment: I guess I'm wondering how you got a width of 476 for the container -- this is about the width of a table in landscape mode (and 320 is the standard width for portrait mode). Are you in landscape mode?

Comment: yes i am in landscape in ipad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've set up an iPhone app to start in landscape mode, and log the table width and cell width, and I get the same thing you see (until I scroll the table, and then it changes the value to the correct wide value). Unless you're subclassing setFrame: in your custom cell, the cell width will be the same as the table width, so why not just use the self.view.frame.size.width (of your view) in your calculations?

Answer (score 1):

Check for this:

```
-(void)layoutSubviews
{
    // Set the UITableView frame here:
    [super layoutSubviews];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
guestTable =  [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,74,320,340)      style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
```

So in the CGRectMake it defines the UITableView. 
Is this what you meant?
It should autoset the cells to the UITableView width.

Comment: No, i initiate my UItableview like this in a controller
    _tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
and in this delegate method
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

i created my custom cell
cell = [[MyOwnCustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                        reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

in the cell's overriden init method, i print its width, which is not same as the tableview...